# Nested functions not allowed in drawrect problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a custom view onto which I draw some graphics from the drawrect function, which works fine.

However I like to draw based on the contens of an array I pass on the the view just before I do a setNeedsDisplay. In the drawRect function If I uses a NSString or NSarray from withing drawRect I get a nested functions error which I do not understand ?

Here's my code:

```
//  MyView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView {
 }
@end

//  MyView.m
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

CGContextRef c;

CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);

     //Gives a nested functions are disabled error at compiletime
     NSString nsz * = @"test";      
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Joe you can, but it's not recommended.  If `nary` is a string that contains a format specifier (like `%@`), then `NSLog()` will try to read data off the stack that's not an actual object and you'll likely crash.  But it's still *possible*.

Comment: The NSLog was just to check it I could see the data in the array (which I could) so it will not be in the code, but no errors from NSLog

Comment: I was using another PC for the mail. But not now/Users/martinstave/Documents/windowIpadOne/../../Downloads/iPhoneLine/MyView.m:134:0 /Users/martinstave/Documents/windowIpadOne/../../Downloads/iPhoneLine/MyView.m:134: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bottom line is that the "nested function" error is just a "general" error you get when you have a really bad syntax error.

Such as forgetting to close a bracket. Or a stray operator.

(Edit -- in fact in this case it was a stray ' * ' operator.)

It actually has nothing to do with "nested functions" (usually), and, the problem could be almost anywhere in the file or even the previous file.

Sorry I could not spot the typo!

Comment: The typo was just that the asterisk for NSString or NSArray originally was on the wrong side an I did not see it !! Actually this whole issue should be removed as it has nothing to do with drawRect, just that you get strange errors if you type and your eyes go blind.!! Do you know how to remove this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray nary;
NSArray ns = [nary objectAtIndex:0];
```

You need an asterisk:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *nary;
NSArray *ns = [nary objectAtIndex:0];
```

Additionally, you should rarely log an object directly.  Instead, use a format string:

```
NSLog(@"%@", nary);
```

Comment: Sorry it was just bad typing, the asterisk was there, butt still the error. 
Martin

Comment: The error is at compile time: Nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to reenable.

Comment: @Martin: how are you compiling this?  In Xcode? On the command line using GCC/clang manually?

Comment: Just spotted the problem, 
With the asterisk on the wrong side !!!!

NSString nsz * = @"test";